# Dúvidas Java - criação de Classes(Objetos)

Tags: java

uma dúvida de iniciante..
Se eu criar um Objeto(Classe) MinhaCalculadora, o valor padrão desse objeto vai ser 0 ou nullo?

Levando em conta q eu declarei apenas variaveis do tipo inteiro na Classe

Answer (score 1):

Todos os tipos **não-primitivos** (classes, arrays, interfaces...) possuem valor default nulo.

Todos os tipos **primitivos** da linguagem **NÃO** se iniciam com valor nulo.

Isto pode ser visto na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No seu caso o `MinhaCalculadora` é uma classe, se você apenas declará-la, por padrão ela terá valor nulo.

Caso você tenha alguma dessas ocasiões que mencionei acima dentro da classe (por exemplo, `MinhaCalculadora` possui um atributo `int`, o valor **do atributo** será `0` por padrão)

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá, tentarei ser o mais claro possível.

> Se eu criar um Objeto(Classe) MinhaCalculadora, o valor padrão desse
>   objeto vai ser 0 ou nullo?

Quando você cria uma novo objeto ele não pode ser nulo. Isso é padrão da linguagem. O que pode acontecer é você criar uma variável com tipo de sua classe sem atribuir um valor.

```
MinhaCalculadora minhaCalculadora;
```

No caso acima, se você não inicializar sua varável e tentar utilizá-la posteriormente, receberá um erro informando que sua variável é nula;

> Levando em conta q eu declarei apenas variaveis do tipo inteiro na
>   Classe

Os atributos da sua classe, os de tipo primitivo, recebem, se não inicializados  explicitamente pelo programador, valores padrão. No seu caso, os inteiros receberão o valor 0.

Answer (score 0):

Tipos primitivos como int, float e double quando não possuem valor definido guardam o valor 0, objetos guardam o valor null quando não possuem valor definido.
A seu objeto MinhaCalculadora irá ter valor null até ser definido um valor para ele, pois ela é um objeto e não um tipo primitivo.
Nota: definir valor = iniciar variável
Nota 2: boolean por exemplo não recebe 0, mas recebe false que é equivalente.
Até mais, espero ter ajudado

Comment: Um objetos não pode ser nulo. Isso seria o mesmo que pontar para lugar nenhum. O que pode acontecer é de uma variável com tipo definido pelo programador não ser inicializada.